# Chat Conversation page design in windows phone using c#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am planning to design a Chat Conversation window and I am thinking of implementing it using a listboxitem template control. So that I can add a new message to the this listbox itemtemplate every time I receive a new message.

do we have any readymade controls which handles this ?

Comment: `Any suggestions to improve this design` - There's no way to improve anything because you are NOT SHOWING ANY CODE OR DESIGNS. -1 and close-voting.

Comment: Wow, score -7 is something I've never seen on this site. :) It seems that OP really tried hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do we have any readymade controls which handles this ?

You mean a control that would cover chat-like functionality ? No, never heard of it. Just bind your messages (observable collection) to the listbox's ItemsSource property. You will have to check every X seconds for a new messages and add them to collection.